# CheckBox com aspeto de RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout

Galera seguinte:
tenho um form no android que conta com alguns radiobutton's e preciso que esses itens possam ser desmarcados quando clicados. Ex: Cliquei no primeiro e ele fica marcado, se eu clicar no segundo radiobutton o primeiro ira continuar marcado só ficando desmarcado quando eu clicar novamente nele.
(Obs. Sei que os checkbox's fazem isso mas nesse caso realmente precisaria que fossem radiobutton's)
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o motivo. Pois este não é o comportamento esperado de um `radioButton`.

Comment: Como eu falei ali em cima eu sei que não é o comportamento esperado. Foi o pedido de um cliente que gostaria que fosse o radioButton, apenas por isso ainda permaneço com a dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o seguinte atributo ao *CheckBox*:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
```

**Exemplo:**

```
<CheckBox style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox"/>
```

Comment: Show Ramaral. Era exatamente isso. Realmente obrigado pela ajuda.